# How to change the default tag path in cakephp views

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I have a little problem with the image path in Cakephp 2.1.3.
right now i have to use:

```
<td background="../../img/login25.png" width="22" height="15"></td>
```

I need to set  the path to the webroot for all tags in my view.
How can i change the path so in my views so that i can use :

```
 <td background="login25.png" width="22" height="15"></td>
```

can some one tell we where and how i can do this?
i looked for hours but all i can find is the path for the $this->Html function ect.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it:

```
 <td background="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/login25.png"  width="22" height="15"></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Erk...may I suggest an alternative approach, and set background images using CSS in a stylesheet? Then the paths will be relative to the stylesheet location.

'background' is not a valid attribute for a td element.

I'm not even going to ask what you're using tables for! ;-)

Comment: Thx but thats not the issue, the path is the same in the css file. inside my css is use background: url("../../img/b_grijs_a.png");  i need background: url("b_grijs_a.png"); i need to set the path

Comment: I can't understand why you 'need' this? I think you're saying that your backgrounds work if you write them one way, but not the other - why do you want to write them the way that doesn't currently work, your requirement doesn't obviously make sense?

Comment: The application is sometimes under the root and sometimes one or more directories deep: images should be referenced correctly in all cases.

Comment: Using a stylesheet will always work though - like I said originally, the paths given in the stylesheet are taken to be relative to the location of the stylesheet (which doesn't change).

Answer (score 0):

```
use css code to call file in td with id or class.


<td class="myimage" width="22" height="15"></td>

use the css code bellow in .css file you are calling or create css file and save to app/webroot/css/ directory.

.myimage { 

  background: url("pathtoimgfolder/b_grijs_a.png");

 }
 For Example : I want to use image from app/webroot/img/a.png
 so I am using :

.myimage { 
   background: url("../img/a.png");
}
```

:)
Happy Coding